# Ctrl key stuck when connect any device to my laptop’s USB port

Tags: windows, usb, keyboard

I have a very weird situation.

If I start my laptop, everything will work fine until I plug in anything in a USB port (like a mouse or external keyboard). The system immediately acts as if the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is pressed (holding <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> will open task manager, press <kbd>v</kbd> will paste, etc…

If I let the mouse and keyboard on and restart, it will work fine until I plug something into the USB port again.

I have this problem before and already reinstalled fresh clean Windows… And it happens even in recovery mode during the installation steps…

Why does this happen and how to fix this? At this point, I’m afraid that it may be a hardware issue.

I'm using a laptop, Asus GL502VM

Comment: It sounds to me like a really,  really weird type of short. If you boot on a live linux USB does it keep doing it?

Comment: When a connector is inserted into the USB port, does it cause the PCB to move slightly. possibly pressing a key contact? Try wiggling the USB plug to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: And you edit the question to add what is the make and model of laptop you are using?

Comment: "Has anyone encountered this problem before?" is not a good question. Is "yes, I have" a *useful* answer? The real question is "why does this happen and how to fix this?", right?

Comment: Is the latest BIOS version installed?